# WPF рисование по вершинам(точкам)

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго дня.

Кто подскажет, что нужно использовать для рисования в WPF, таким образом.

Мышкой кликаем по области тем самым задавая точки(вершины) для будущего многоугольника, и затем он по ним рисуется, например если кол-во точек достигло 5, то между ними рисуются линии, как-то так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно в обработчике событий вашего контейнера при событии Mouse Click отлавливать координаты и сохранять (например в массив), при этом выполняя проверку-если запомнили все 5(или сколько вам надо) точек,тогда рисуем многоугольник при помощи `Graphics.DrawPolygon`

Comment: Есть ли такое событие, которое захватывает координаты?

Comment: @SOFL, какой-нибудь MouseDown